# IDEA decompile instead of download source code from maven when click into source code

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In `Eclipse`, when `ctrl` + `left click` into a type of 3rd party library from maven repository, it will download the source code jar automatically, then show the source code of that type.

But, it seems `IDEA` *(2018 version)* simply decompile the .class files, and show the result, without downloading the source code.

**The question is:**

- How to let IDEA download source code jar file from maven, and show the actual source code, when click into a type? (Just like what Eclipse does.)

Comment: IDEA allows you to get the source code instead of decompiled. It works automatically, but sometimes you have to click "download sources" on the top of the editor, when the decompiled class is shown. If you don't have this option, you better to research this problem, or provide more details about your case.

Comment: Maybe you should tick `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing -> automatically download sources`?

Comment: @AxelP Ok, you are right, there do have a `download sources` link on top right of decompiled code, I didn't notice it ... the IDEA color was so dark ... Anyway, now I can download it.

Comment: @AxelP I did checked `automatically download sources`, but seems still need to click `download sources`, or maybe it's already downloading, it's just not finished yet? I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has an option to download the sources automatically:

[image: download sources]

If you enable it in the existing project, you will need to Reimport in the Maven tool window to get the sources downloaded, or use the button to forcibly download the sources:

[image: Reimport]

[image: Download]

Yet another option is to **Download sources** or specify the sources location manually via the panel at the top of the decompiled file in the editor:

[image: Download sources]

Comment: I disabled the auto download for source code, for some projects there are too many dependencies, and I only check source code of very few of them, so downloading all their source code is not necessary. I want it to download the source code when I click into it on need. Any as the comments under the questions says, there is a download sources link on top of the de-compiled code, which help to trigger downloading of source code, so it's also working & acceptable.

Comment: @EricWang That is also a working solution, I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Do you think it's better to add an option that could enable download of source code automatically when click into the type, so that no need to click `download sources` by hand again?

Comment: @EricWang I don't think adding another option would make it easier to use, it will only provide more confusion. If you want it to work automatically, just download all the sources for the project and there will be no questions asked.

Comment: I think it differently, because currently it's either everything (download all source on import) or nothing (unless additionally click the `download sources`). Another option would be like download on first checking its source code (automatically without additionally click the button). But, you are right people might feel this confusion if they haven't get into the situation as I have, though a good description could erase that in a great degree. Anyhow, click the `download source` button once for each jar is acceptable to me, so it's fine.